# Text not wrapping around floated image

Tags: css-float

I've been struggling with this issue for a while and none of the solutions I've found on google or stackoverflow have worked for me.

I'm building a site for a class project and I've got several divs within each other (I have a feeling this is what's tripping it up) to contain the elements where they're supposed to go, like so:

```
    <div id="page">

    <a href="index.html">
        <div id="banner">
            <img src="images\banner2.png" alt="Banner" width="980" height="130">
        </div> <!-- banner -->
    </a>

    <div id="navalign">
        <div id="header">ATV 1</div> 
        <img class="illustration" src="images\placeholder.png" alt="ATV Placeholder 1" width="250" height="250">
        <p class="bodytext"><br><br>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt 
            ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco 
            laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in 
            voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat 
            cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
```

The placeholder image is set to align to the right of the containing div (#navalign) and float, while the text wraps around it.  Instead the text is wrapping within #navalign and passing over the floated image.

Here are the classes for the body text and the image:

```
img.illustration {
position: absolute;
float: right;
right: 0px;
width: 250px;
margin: 0 0 10px 10px;
display: inline-block;}

p.bodytext {
position: absolute;
margin: 0 auto;
margin-top: 10px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
margin-left: 40px;
left: 150px;
/*top: 40px; */
z-index: 5;
float: left;}
```

I've tried just about everything I can think of to get this to work and there's probably some extra bits of stuff in those classes that shouldn't be there where I tried stuff and forgot to delete it when it didn't work.  The only thing I can think of is that containing the two elements within other divs is what's causing it to not wrap, but I don't know how to fix that without rewriting the whole site.

Comment: That's because your `p` is positioned absolute. Change your `p` to `position: relative`, ... or put your image inside it.

Answer (score 0):

That's because your `p` and `img` is positioned absolute. Here is a part of your sample which does work.

```css
img.illustration {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="navalign">
  <div id="header">ATV 1</div> 
  <img class="illustration" src="http://placeholder.com" alt="ATV Placeholder 1" width="250" height="250">
  <p class="bodytext"><br><br>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt 
    ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco 
    laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in 
    voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat 
    cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt 
    ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco 
    laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in 
    voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat 
    cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.  </p>
</div>
```